# Call Compare Method from another class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Please help me to resolve the following problem:
First of all, I have one class

```
namespace ProbA
{

    public class A : IComparer
    {
        Private int a;
        public int IComparer.Compare(object CurrentNode, object DataNode)
        {
            WBPMember Current = (WBPMember)CurrentNode;
            WBPMember Data = (WBPMember)DataNode;
            return Current.a- Data.a;
        }
    }
}



 namespace BST
{

public class BinarySearchTree<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
    {
public virtual void Add(T data)
        {
            // create a new Node instance
            BinaryTreeNode<T> n = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(data);
            int result;

            BinaryTreeNode<T> current = root, parent = null;
            while (current != null)
            {
      result = /**** I need to call the Class A compare method.     
     }
}
    }
}
```

I want to execute ClassA Compare method, when following statement execute in  ProbA assembly.

```
A objA = new A();
BinarySearchTree<A> bst = new BinarySearchTree<A>();
Bst.Add(objA);
```

Problem is both classes are in different libraries. And BinarySearchTree is generic class. So how can i compare A typed object in Add function of BinarySearchTree class.

---

I update this post for more clarification. 
Let me describe my problem more clearly.
I have some type of businessrules. And as per different business rules , I need to construct different type of BST. Offcouse, BST generates at the same logic but on the different kind of logic of comparision.

Lets say, I have BusineesRules assembly. And it contains 4 kind of rules like Business1, Business2, Business3. Business4. 
And I have an assembly for generating BST and other traversal methods. This BST is fully generic and in assembly BST
Now when I need to implement compare method in each class. 
Like,.

```
Public Class Business1: IComparer
{
    // Implemetation of Icompare.
}
```

Same for all the other classes.

When I try to add instance of Business1 in BST,  make comparision based on its own implementation and same for other classes.

Code for BST is given below:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
    {
        #region "Private Member Variables"
        private BinaryTreeNode<T> root = null;
        private int count = 0;
        private IComparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;    // used to compare node values when percolating down the tree
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public BinarySearchTree() { }
        public BinarySearchTree(IComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            this.comparer = comparer;
        }
        #endregion

public virtual void Add(T data)
        {
            // create a new Node instance
            BinaryTreeNode<T> n = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(data);
            int result;

            // now, insert n into the tree
            // trace down the tree until we hit a NULL
            BinaryTreeNode<T> current = root, parent = null;
            while (current != null)
            {
                result = comparer.Compare(current.Value, data);                
                if (result == 0)
                    // they are equal - attempting to enter a duplicate - do nothing
                    return;
                else if (result > 0)
                {
                    // current.Value > data, must add n to current's left subtree
                    parent = current;
                    current = current.Left;
                }
                else if (result < 0)
                {
                    // current.Value < data, must add n to current's right subtree
                    parent = current;
                    current = current.Right;
                }
            }

            // We're ready to add the node!
            count++;
            if (parent == null)
                // the tree was empty, make n the root
                root = n;
            else
            {
                result = comparer.Compare(parent.Value, data);
                if (result > 0)
                    // parent.Value > data, therefore n must be added to the left subtree
                    parent.Left = n;
                else
                    // parent.Value < data, therefore n must be added to the right subtree
                    parent.Right = n;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

**** Add Generic comparer method.
This following class is added into businessrule classes assembly.

```
class BusinessRules: IComparer
    {

        public int Compare(object CurrentHNode, object DataNode)
        {
            TreeMember Current;
            TreeMember Data;

            if (CurrentHNode is Current)
            {
                Current = (TreeMember)CurrentHNode;
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Object is not type of WBPMember");

            if (DataNode is Data)
            {
                Data = (TreeMember)DataNode;
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Object is not type of WBPMember");

            return Current.TreeIndex - Data.TreeIndex;
        }
    }
```

You can see following line in the code.
“result = comparer.Compare(current.Value, data);”
But it is compare of binarysearch class. So I can call compare method business1 or business2.?
Is this comparor implemetation useful to compare objects in BinarySearchTree.Add() method?
One more important thing is that BST and other businessrule classes are different assemblies.

Comment: What is your question? Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: Problem is both classes are in different libraries. And BinarySearchTree is generic class. So how can i compare A typed object in Add function of BinarySearchTree class.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add the question to it, instead of a comment.

Comment: Exctaly I want syntax for getting result value in Add method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you want to call `Compare`, your `BinarySearchTree` class will need to have a reference to an instance of the comparer. Assuming you want to make the binary search tree consistent, it seems logical to use the same comparer for all operations acting on a single instance of the search tree. I would suggest that:

- You change your `A` class to implement `IComparer<WBPMember>` instead of just `IComparer`
- You create a constructor in `BinarySearchTree` which takes an `IComparer<T>` and remembers it for later.
- You optionally create a parameterless constructor in `BinarySearchTree` using the default comparer for `T`

Something like this:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IComparer<T> comparer;

    public BinarySearchTree(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        // TODO: Work out how to handle comparer == null (could throw an
        // exception, could use the default comparer).
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    public BinarySearchTree() : this(Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    // Now within Add, you can call comparer.Compare(current.Value, data)
}
```

Comment: Here I have already implemented your second suggestion. And I need to a syntax. 
I wrote "result = current.Value.Compare(data);" but this syntax is not  working. 
here current.Value contains <T> which is instance of Class A  or instance of WBPMember class instance.

Comment: @hiren: Look at the comment within my sample code. You want to call a method on the comparer, right? So *call the method on the comparer*. Calling `current.Value.Compare` is calling `Compare` on the *value*, not on the *comparer*, isn't it?

Comment: I was consfused because of Current and data both are instance of <T>. So i have passed instance of Class A, called objA in bst.Add(obj).

Then I want to some syntax which could be called an compare method which is implemented in Class A.
public class A : TreeMember, IComparer
    {
        public int IComparer.Compare(object CurrentNode, object DataNode)
        {
            A Current = (A)CurrentNode;
            A Data = (A)DataNode;

            return Current.TreeIndex - Data.TreeIndex;
        }
    }

Comment: @hiren: No, `data` is of type `T`, but `current` is of type `BinaryTreeNode<T>`. I've edited my answer. It's not clear what `WBPMember` is meant to represent, but it almost certainly shouldn't implement `IComparer` itself.

Comment: @hiren: In short, it's not clear whether the source of your confusion is that you haven't really separated in your mind the concepts of "comparer" and "value to be compared" or whether you're having trouble with C# itself. This is a pretty simple bit of C# - just calling a method on one object, passing in arguments to say what to compare - so that bit should be easy, unless you're completely new to C# (in which case I'd suggest doing something simpler to start with).

Comment: please see the same post. I have update some more stuff. 
sorry because of i cant give you clear idea because of language barrier.

Comment: @hiren: Given your edited post, it looks like the only problem is that it's using the default comparer for the type. When you construct the `BinarySearchTree<T>`, you should pass in your custom comparer. As I said before, you should implement the generic `IComparer<T>` interface instead of using the nongeneric `IComparer`.

Comment: user name:@Jon Skeet. Ohhh.. I see. I understand ..
But first let me implement this generic IComparer.

Comment: hey @Jon Skeet.  
I have tried to implement generic IComparer. But i cant get any success.
Coudld you write some valuable lines of code for me which will resolve my above given problem? 

and thank you very much to helping me.

Comment: hey @Jon Skeet and other geeks,
I have updated this post and add some code for IComparer implemetation. Please see it and tell me is it right way to resolve this problem.

Comment: @hiren: I still see no sign of you trying to implement `IComparer<T>`, and your `IComparer` implementation looks dubious to say the least - what are the `Current` and `Data` types which you're checking with `is`? As I said before, if you're new to C# I would start with something simpler if I were you...

Comment: @skeet: You can see the BinarySearch Code by this link, from there I also got it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @skeet:I think i am able to show you what is exactly my problem with the above link. 
I need to just move this comparision in another library (BSTTester in above example).

Comment: @Skeet: I got a solution after doing reading some chapters and MSDN for ICompare. 
I have inherited System.IComparable<WBPMember> to the my businessrule class and now it is working.
I just do the following code:
public Class BusinessRule1 : System.IComparable<WBPMember>
{
     public int CompareTo(BusinessRule1 objBR)
     {
         /** code as per business logic
     }
}